# Show using ordering axioms that $x^2 < y^2$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{Q}$, with $0 < x < y$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, rational-numbers, ordered-fields

I have an exercise in my last assignment of calculus:

> Show using ordering axioms that $$x^2 < y^2$$ for $x, y \in
> > \mathbb{Q}$, with $0 < x < y$

This is my solution:

---

We have that $x < y$.

Since $x > 0$, we can multiply both sides of the previous inequality by $x$ (Order axiom *compatability*), and we obtain:

1. $$x \cdot x < y \cdot x$$

Now, we know also that $y > 0$, so also in this case we can multiply both sides of the inequality $x < y$ by $y$:

2. $$x \cdot y < y \cdot y$$

Since all field axioms apply also to the set $\mathbb{Q}$, we can use them; in particular the field axiom 2 (Field axiom *commutativity*). We have that:

$$x \cdot y = y \cdot x$$

If we replace $y \cdot x$ by $x \cdot y$ in inequality $1.$, we obtain:

$$x \cdot x < x \cdot y$$

Since we have both $x \cdot x < x \cdot y$ and $x \cdot y < y \cdot y$, by transitivity we have:

$$x \cdot x < y \cdot y$$

Since $x \cdot x = x^2$ and $y \cdot y = y^2$, we have:

$$x^2 < y^2$$

---

The thing I am not convinced about is my suppositions that $a \cdot a = a^2$. Should I also show it?

Comment: $a\cdot a=a^2$ is the definition of the square, so you usually don't need to prove it.  Also, you should have used transitivity at the end.  Other than that, it looks good.

Comment: Yes, in general, if $a< b$ and $b < c$, then $a < c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your proof looks good.

**Alternative Approach**

If you have defined $u<v$ as "$v-u$ is a positive number," you might have also proved or assumed that the positive rationals are closed under addition and multiplication.

Then you can show that $y^2-x^2 = (y-x)(y+x)$, which is true by the distributive law and commutativity of multiplication. So since $y-x$ is positive (since $x<y$) and $y+x$ is positive (since the sum of positive numbers is positive) we have that $y^2-x^2$ is positive (since positives are closed under multiplication.)

So $x^2<y^2$.

This proof is, essentially, the same as your proof, but more basic.